# Opening a new activity on button click

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I have looked at every example of switching between activities and I always get the same result.  The app bombs.

As far as I can tell if you have a java class that populates the content of a layout then in order to switch to the other layout, you must 'link' to the java file which in turn will open the setContentView(R.layout.whatever);

When I try to do this, like I say my app bombs out.  My code is as follows:-

FROM Java class:-

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goesnews);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ac2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);   




}
```

TO java file (ac2)

```
     public class ac2 extends Activity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main2);

     }}
```

Can anyone help out here?

Comment: what is the error log. have you declare the activity in manifest?

Comment: use startActivity(myIntent);, you can (should) use getApplicationContext(); instead of view.getContext(); also make sure you have declared you activity in androidmanifest.xml like <activity android:name="packagename.Activityname></activity>

Comment: logcat error logs would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the zero from this line:

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

like this and change it to just:

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and change this line:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ac2.class);
```

To this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivityName.this, ac2.class);
```

because you are getting here the context of the button and not of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

add onclick function to your button in xml file 
like this

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/previous" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="click"
        android:onClick="move" />
```

and in ur java file 
make a function move like this

```
public void move(View v)
{
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourclass.this, ac2.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
 }
```

Comment: VSK - when trying your method, I can't save and compile the app as I get an error - The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Intent)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple and was based on the response from VSK (Thanks) with a little tweak.

The ImageButton required :-

```
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/previous" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="click"
    android:onClick="move" />
```

Java required:-

```
    public void move(View v)
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourclass.this, ac2.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
```

VSK - please note '0' attribute of startActivityForResult

Thanks all